# two list manipulation on columns

Tags: list-manipulation

I have three pairs of list and need two divide second column of first list by second column of the second list. Furthermore, I have to do for all three pairs.  My data list are tagged aa[1]...aa[3] therefore I cannot change code to change the way they are listed.  Below is example,

```
aa[1] = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}; (*first pair*)
aa[2] = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}; 
aa[3] = {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}; 

bb[1] = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}; (*second pair*)
bb[2] = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}; 
bb[3] = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}; 


Do[aa[ii][[All, 2]] = aa[ii][[All, 2]]/bb[ii][[All, 2]], {ii, 3}];
```

But Mathematica version 9 is complaining and not doing this.  What is wrong with my code? To make it work, I have to do this three times:

```
aa1 = aa[1];
bb1 = bb[1];
aa1[[All, 2]] = aa1[[All, 2]]/bb1[[All, 2]];
```

Is there a way to simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ReplacePart` instead of `Part` assignment works:

```
Quiet@Do[aa[i] = ReplacePart[aa[i], {r_, 2} :> aa[i][[r, 2]]/(bb[i][[r, 2]])], {i, 3}];

{aa[1], aa[2], aa[3]} // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Here's another way of doing things, if you want to set `a[1]` et. al. to the new updated lists:

```
{a[1], a[2], a[3]} = MapThread[#1[[All, 2]]/#2[[All, 2]] &, {Array[a, 3], Array[b, 3]}]
```

**Original Post**

How about this instead?

```
a = {{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}},
     {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}},
     {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}};
b = {{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}},
     {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}},
     {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}};
```

Then:

```
MapThread[#1[[All, 2]]/#2[[All, 2]] &, {a, b}]
(* {{2, 1/4, 1/4, 1, 2}, {1, 1/3, 3/2, 1, 0}, {0, 1, ComplexInfinity, 2, 2}} *)
```

This will throw an error because of the dividing by zero.

Comment: I cannot change a[1]...to a.  The reason is that already have a code to do integral and plots for a[1], a[2] and so on.  Looks like I have to go for a loop.

Comment: Then define aa={a[1], a[2], a[3]} and same for b.

Comment: Once I did the division part, how do I revert back to a[1],a[2] and a[3] from aa?    a[3]=aa[[All,4]]  and  a[2]=aa[[All,3]] and so on.  Is that right approach?

Comment: @Aschoolar: I mean, sure, but what are you really trying to do? Defining three different objects `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]` seems like overkill when you can just the list `a` instead.  It makes things easier to automate in  my opinion. In any case, I've updated my post with maybe a more straightforward way of doing things.